# jQuery make select option 'selected'

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-selectors

I have a basic question regarding jQuery.

I have a static time-selection box IE:

```
<select name="startTime" class="startTime">
  <option value="00:00:00">12:00am</option>
  <option value="00:15:00">12:15am</option>
  <option value="00:30:00">12:30am</option>
  <option value="00:45:00">12:45am</option>
  etc...
</select>
```

So when I run my MySQL Query I pull a date from the database, and I want to make a specific time frame selected

my database returns a value such as,   "00:30:00" *date(H:i:s)*
So I need to make "00:30:00" the selected value with jQuery, and i'm not exactly sure how to make that happen.

I thought it was something like this:

```
$(".startTime").val('<?php echo $timeStart; ?>');
```

Perhaps someone could shed some light.

Comment: What you wrote should work. Something else is going on. Are you sure the value of `$timeStart` is being inserted into your JS correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use the element tag name in the selector for efficiency

```
 $("select.startTime")
```

Second you should check what the value of `<?php echo $timeStart; ?>` is, because the following should work.

```
 $("select.startTime").val('<?php echo $timeStart; ?>');
```

Comment: Yeah it seemed as though there was another irritating glitch, so the code did work... sorry to throw out this question. But thanks for your replies! Cheers. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a handy cheatsheet for jQuery and Select elements: [cheatsheet](http://comp345.awardspace.com/select_element_cheatsheet.pdf)
If you are going to be working with them it'll come in handy.

Comment: People need a cheat sheet just for `select` and jQuery?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are cheat sheets for just about everything now. Nothing wrong with having a quick reference on hand tho :P

Answer (score 1):

You want HTML:

```
<select id="startTime" class="startTime">
```

And javascript:

```
$("#startTime").val('<?php echo $timeStart; ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the selected item on page load, you could try some thing like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
<?php 
      $your_query_return="00:15:00";
?>
      $('select.startTime').val("<?php echo your_query_return;?>").attr('selected','selected');
});

</script>
```

If you put the script above on your head tag of the page, it should work. The same procedure can give you same result even you if you want to use ajax.